# Install some parts of the DevExtreme UI component in my project

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

Actually, I am going to use the DevExtreme chart in my angular project.
Is it possible to install just the DevExtreme chart pack instead of the full package in my project?
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can install only **DevExtreme chart** instead of the full package for that you need to study the documentation of DevExtreme.

Here you can check [Support center of devExtreme](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t686850/how-to-install-the-devextreme-charts-library-only).

Here is how to [Use](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/Modularity/Link_Modules/)